# Text Area in JSP Enter to implement a functionality

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc, textarea

I am using Spring MVC and I have created a textArea in it, I want to add a functionality: When user presses 'Enter' two times the cursor will automatically go to next line and indicate the paragraph number in the new line:

Here is the code for TextArea:

```
<textarea   name="notings" style="width:800px ; height:200px" ></textarea>
```

Example:

1. Users types something ...
   ................................ //Presses enter key 2 times consecutively
2. types something else....

I am clueless in implementing this functionality. I am a starter at front end development and don't know javascript as well. A little help will be much appreciated.

If someone could point me towards the right direction, that will also help alot

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try this way

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var pn=1;
        var count=0;
    function newLineFun(e)
    {
    if(e.keyCode==13)
        {
        count++;
        if(count==2)
        {
        count=0;
        var oldData=$("#txtArea").val();
        $("#txtArea").val(oldData+pn);
        pn++;
        }
        }
        else{
        count=0;
        }

    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<textarea  id="txtArea" name="notings" style="width:800px ; height:200px" onkeypress="newLineFun(event)"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```